# How to get all post of custom post type by rest api?

Tags: custom-post-types, rest-api

I have CPT transcript in wordpress website. And create 250 post in CPT transcript.

Now, I want to fetch all transcript data and want to store in another database using rest api url **http://example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/transcript/**

AND

HTTP request using CURL

```
$ch = curl_init();
$url = 'http://example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/transcript/'; 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
return curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

But this return only 10 transcript,

Please help me, how to retrieve all transcript post data.

Comment: I believe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35728943/wordpress-rest-api-v2-return-all-posts) is what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

The REST API supports grabbing a maximum of 100 posts at a time, so you'll have to make an additional call for every 100.

Start with `wp_remote_get()` for 100 posts. While you're at it, go ahead and retrieve the body of this page and decode it:

```
$transcripts = wp_remote_get('http://example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/transcript/?per_page=100');
$transcriptsBody = wp_remote_retrieve_body($transcripts);
$transcriptsDecoded = json_decode($transcriptsBody, true);
```

Next, identify how many pages of 100 currently exist:

`$numPages = wp_remote_retrieve_header($transcripts, 'x-wp-totalpages');`

Then, if there's more than 1 page, grab each additional page. Start at page 2, since you've already grabbed page 1.

```
if($numPages > 1) {
    for($i=2; $i<($numPages+1); $i++) {
        // Identify the next endpoint to call
        $nextUrl = 'http://example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/transcript/?per_page=100&page=' . $i;
    }
    // Remote_get that endpoint
    $nextPage = wp_remote_get("$nextUrl");
    // Set a variable variable name for the next page
    $bodyVar = 'transcripts' . $i;
    // Get the body of the current page
    $$bodyVar = wp_remote_retrieve_body($nextPage);
    // Set a variable variable name for the decoded body
    $decodeVar = 'transcriptsDecoded' . $i;
    // Decode the JSON
    $$decodeVar = json_decode(${$bodyVar}, true);
    // Finally, merge the posts into the existing decoded array
    $transcriptsDecoded = array_merge($transcriptsDecoded, $$decodeVar);
}
```

You'll now have a PHP array of all of the posts, no matter how few or many posts there are.

Note that if you pull using the REST API and save the posts to a different database, you'll have a static copy. If anyone updates, deletes, or adds to the original site, your copy won't be in sync. So, it's more common to build the REST API calls into the code of the other site where you want to display the content, so that it reaches out and grabs the specific content you want to display right then and there. (And ideally, caches that for at least a few hours or days, so you're not constantly waiting on data to reload.)

Comment: Thanks, Its working fine

Answer (score 1):

You can as suggested in one of the comments add `&filter[posts_per_page]=250` but that is a pretty big response that may not be handled very well at either end.

Maybe a better approach as suggested [under pagination](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/using-the-rest-api/pagination/) is to add `?per_page=100` on the first request and then make a few additional requests with `?per_page=1&page=2` etc.

If you find that 100 at a time is still to high, try a lower number and request additional pages as needed.

If you need help with looping and/or concatenation, let me know and I can expand this.